# Two Rewrite Rules

Tags: url-rewriting

I have one folder inside WordPress root folder named links and there is a file called index.php inside this folder. at somewhere else in my WordPress site I do generate links such as http://mysite.com/links/index.php?link=55 (there are more than one link).

How can I have specific rewrite rule (like http://mysite.com/link/55) for above link inside my .htaccess file that don't interrupt own WordPress rule and don't throw Internal Server Error?

Here is my .htaccess content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^link/([^/]*)$ /wordpress/links/index.php?link=$1 [L]

RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Currently I am on localhost and my wordpress folder is in /www/wordpress. but when I click  `http://localhost/link/50a25386721bb` I get 404 error. what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Catch those requests before WordPress can see them:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^link/(\d+)$ /links/index.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Place the WordPress rules **below** the link rules.

Comment: Please read first post as I did edit that based on what you said. thanks.

Comment: @silvercover Try the rule I suggested, your variation cannot work.

Comment: I've changed (\d+) to ([^/]*) because passed parameter may contain alpha numeric characters. I've also added [L,QSA] at the end but again I get 404!